# Is there a built-in method to wait for an element to match some text?

Tags: webdriver, webdriver-io

We test our [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) typically by going to some page, do an action to save a value, then check that the new value is being displayed. Since everything is being updated async, that means the new value can take some time to appear. So either the previous value can linger around for a little time, or the element we are checking the text for might not yet exist.

This is so far what we have come up with every time I want to "check that eventually an element with this selector contains this text":

```
// we need to wait for the text, because the result is async updated
// - the previous result might linger around for some time, or 
// the element might not even exist, failing the `getText()` call

const selector = '.feed-item div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2)';
browser.waitForText(selector);
browser.waitUntil(() => browser.getText(selector) === 'Temp: 20');
```

This works, but it's a bit much boilerplate, and it feels strange not to have it included, as it seems like a pretty natural thing to do in all client-side rendered applications.

Is there a better pattern for doing this, using WebDriver.io, preferably doing this in one go? All the 1-line variations I have tried either asserts on the wrong element or fails due to not finding one (as the result has yet to come).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try two things:

**Add [a custom command](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/addCommand.html):**

```
browser.addCommand('waitForContent', function (selector, text) {
    browser.waitForText(selector);
    browser.waitUntil(() => browser.getText(selector) === text);
})

browser.waitForContent('.feed-item div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2)', 'Temp: 20')
```

**Use [a text-based selector](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html#Element-with-certain-text):**

`browser.waitForExist('.feed-item div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2)*=Temp: 20')`

This specific selector may not work, as I haven't tested it when there are child selectors in there.

[I've got videos covering both](https://learn.webdriver.io) if you're interested in more details.

Comment: The last selector will not work, as it only matches on elements (which would be too broad), not CSS selectors (it's using XPath). I ended up using the first approach, as a crutch, but yours have a bug, resulting in a NPE, which I'll fix up in an edit :-)